# Why am I getting different quotes, at the same time, between uniswap website and the router v2 contract?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv2

If I run the queries at the same time, I would expect very approximate results, if not the exact same, but that's not what I get between the Uniswap's website and the Router V2 contract as you can see below.

[image: In the website I get a 2.46 ETH quote]

[image: In the contract I get a 2.45 ETH quote]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uniswap V2 and V3 are different versions of the Uniswap protocol and have some significant differences, including the way liquidity is managed and how trades are executed, in website is working uniswap V3 pool logic and getAmountsOut is V2 function, in V3 to get amount out is using Quoter contract (but it is no gas efficient it uses in callback or off-chain). So V2 and V3 are separate contracts and ecosystems. The liquidity in Uniswap V2 pools is not shared with Uniswap V3 pools. Each version has its own set of pools and liquidity providers

Comment: Any advantage on using V3 Quoter instead of V2 for trading, given that as you mention Quote is less efficient in gas usage?

Comment: Uniswap V3 Quoter is designed specifically for Uniswap V3. Uniswap V2 and V3 have different liquidity models. Uniswap V2 uses a constant product formula, where liquidity is evenly spread across all price levels within a pool. The calculation of prices and trading amounts differs between Uniswap V2 and V3. Uniswap V2's getAmountsOut function provides a simple way to estimate output amounts based on the available liquidity in the pool, Uniswap V3's Quoter offers more advanced calculations, taking into account concentrated liquidity, customized price ranges, and fee tiers.

Comment: When you deciding between Uniswap V2 and V3, it's crucial to consider the specific use case and requirements. If the use case benefits from concentrated liquidity, fee optimization, and customizable price ranges, Uniswap V3 may be more suitable. Otherwise, Uniswap V2's simplicity and widespread adoption could make it a better choice.